# Export table description in PHPMyAdmin/MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
 DESC table_name
```

Above SQL allows me to get the table description in PHPMyAdmin. I want to export it to a text file or word file for the documentation. Is there a possible way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily using [SELECT...INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) statement reading data from [`information_schema`.`tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html) or `information_schema`.`columns` table -

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables INTO OUTFILE dump_tables.csv
```

The query will output resultset into specified CSV-file.